# Auto-Implemented Properties Error

Tags: c#, .net

I try to use AIP

```
public int AIP_NoSet
{
    get { ;}
}
```

Compiler say that it is an error: 

Program.c1.AIP_NoSet.get': not all code paths return a value

But even if I write

`public int AIP_NoSet
{
    get { ;}
    set { ;}
}`

it shows me the same error.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A moment of derp.

```
public int AIP_NoSet { get; set; }
```

---

Sounds like you want an automatic property with only a 'get' defined.

This is not allowed by the compiler.

You can accomplish this by adding a `private` set (as others have answered), or by not using an automatic property:

```
private int _aip = int.MaxValue;
public int AIP_NoSet { get {return _aip;}}
```

Or, if you NEVER want to set it, just use a const:

```
public const int AIP_NoSet = 2;
```

Comment: But what if i need only set and only get?

Comment: Only set public int AIP_NoGet
        {
            set { ;}
        }

Comment: @Sergey what good would an auto-implemented property be that only has a get?  You wouldn't ever be able to SET it.  Its not allowed by the framework.

Comment: If you make only a `get` accessor you can never set the property to anything!

Comment: I just want to try. I know that they are not useful. But Why Only set is allowed, but only Get doesnt allowed?

Comment: @Sergey because you could never set.  So there is absolutely no reason for the compiler team to sit down and write the code to do this.

Comment: But I could get a default value. If i havent got GET, i can never get the property value, only set. But its allowed

Comment: If you have only a `get` you can't set it to a default value.  There is absolutely no use for it.  Why complicate the language with useless cruft?

Comment: Does property get its default type value? If its int, AIP_NoSet will always return 0.

Comment: @Sergey The compiler team decided flat out not to support this scenario because it made no sense whatsoever and the specification of the language did not specify that this scenario is to be supported.  If they don't support it, then it doesn't exist in the language.

Answer (score 4):

You should write

```
public int AIP { get; set; }
```

when you write `{ ;}` after it, this is seen as a syntacticaly incorrect attempt of a user implemented property. You can't have no setter, but you can make the setter private:

```
public int AIP_PrivateSet { get; private set; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Make setter access private and fix syntax.

```
public int AIP_NoSet { get; private set; }
```